# Appearance of font-weight across all browsers?

Tags: css, windows, macos, fonts

I am using font-weight: 300; for a text .  The funny thing is that appears perfectly on a mac, but when i go to windows the font appears thinner but not as the same as it does on the mac.  Any thing i am missing that i need to do for windows browsers?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Why yes, font rendering works and looks entirely differently across different systems. You cannot make it look entirely identical. You should learn what users of different systems expect and make it look normal.

[image: avm]

Also see [Font Rendering: Respecting The Pixel Grid](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/06/font-rendering-respecting-the-pixel-grid.html) and [Font smoothing, anti-aliasing, and sub-pixel rendering](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2007/06/12.html).

Answer (score 0):

This `font-weight: 300;` is differently interpreted. I normally choose only `font-weight: bold;` and that's it. It's more common across browsers.

However as with anything font, you don't even know if the useragent that displays your HTML/CSS has even that font, so I won't be concerned about this too much anyway. The problem is your expectation, not the actual rendering. Accept the fact, that you don't have control over the users computers that much. If you like to, render your page as a big PNG image and transfer that instead of your website.